# minIndex of array elements

Tags: java, arrays

This largest issue i'm having is figuring out the difference between an element and indices. I'm sure this method has something to do with the .length property of an array but, alas, i'm not sure. This is the exact description of the method i'm trying to figure out, from my professor.

"Define a private static helper method `minIndex(int[ ] nums, int start)` such that it returns the index of the smallest element of the upper section of the nums array between start and the end of the array".

Can anyone try to decipher this and give me some insight on how to create this method?

Comment: The difference between them is quite simple: the element is what is put into the array and the corresponding index describes the position of the element in the array

Comment: So if I was told to find the minIndex that returns the smallest element of the upper section of the nums array between start and the end of the array, it simply means that my professor wants the minValue of my elements?

Comment: I don't know what the condition 'of the upper section' shall mean, but almost right. He doesn't want the minValue, but the index of the minValue.

Comment: @JesseKeefer the question is that find the index of smallest element from the range ( `start - nums.length` ) – see the answer

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking to find index of the smallest element from the range ( `start - nums.length` ), i.e upper section

an array is a contiguous collection of elements. each element has an index(integer) that can be used to access each element from the array.

Here is the code: This code returns the index of the smallest number on the upper section and returns `-1` if `start` is out of the range of indexes.

```
public class IndexofElement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int[] nums  = {12,4,5,9,45,6,2,4,6,7,8};
       int index = minIndex(nums,2);
        System.out.println("The Index of smallest num is  : " + index);

    }

public static int minIndex(int[ ] nums, int start){
    int sIndex = start;
    if (start >= nums.length | start < 0 )
        return -1;  
    for(int i=start+1;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]<nums[sIndex])
                sIndex=i;       
    }
    return sIndex;
}
}
```

p.s I created the class for purpose of testing.

**input:**

```
int[] nums  = {12,4,5,9,45,6,2,4,6,7,8};
```

**output:**

```
The Index of smallest num is  : 6
```